# inno setup install SQL database with parameters

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup

i'm searching for help to install a SQL database with inno setup.
i'm a newbie and i don't know how to write right code.

i need to run createdb.sql with connection parameters to sql instance + choose the directory location of my DB files.
it's possible?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: the db is MSSQL . i found the example CodeAutomation.iss and i'm trying to understand if it can help me , but when i run it nothing appears

Answer (score 1):

solved with this code

```
    [Code]


  procedure ButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
   var
  Params: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;

begin
  if MsgBox('Setup will now create CLIP Database ', mbInformation, mb_YesNo) = idNo then
      Params := '-v CLIPDATA="C:\dev\CLIP" CLIPINDEX="C:\dev\CLIP" CLIPLOG="C:\dev\CLIP" -S localhost\WISE -U sa -P wadmwadm -i "C:\Users\aartoni\Documents\innosetup\input\CLIP\Materiale di supporto\Installazione\DB\Create Database 2.12.3.sql';
      Exec ('sqlcmd',Params, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) 
    Exit;
end;
```